# Numerically stable algorithm to find most likely

Tags: optimization, algorithms, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have $N$ Normal random variables $x_i$, each one with mean and variance $\mu_i$, $\sigma^2_i$. Given a value $L$, is there a numerically stable way to compute which of those has the higher probability of being higher than $L$? More formally, I want to find $k$ such that

$k = \arg\max_{i} P(x_i > L | \mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$

What I'm doing now is computing, for each $x_i$, the cumulative distribution -the probability of $x_i < L$- but if $L$ is high enough the computation of the cdf returns 0 due to loss of precision. What I ideally would like to have is a way to tell which $x_i$ has the highest probability of being higher than L without actually computing that probability (since I'm not interested in it).

Comment: You might consider computing the logarithm of the probability rather than the probability itself.

Comment: But how do I compute the log of the cumulative distribution? Is the integral of the log density good for this purpose? (even though log of integral and integral of log are not equivalent in general)